# Searching using unordered map vs array

Tags: c++, arrays, unordered-map

I have a block allocation function that takes in an array and then searches through it to find values `0` which indicates the free space, and then allocates blocks to the available free space. I am trying to use unordered map to improve the speed of searching for `0`s. In my function, all the elements in the array are inserted into the unordered map. I was wondering if implementing unordered map like below even improves the searching speed compared to just using arrays?

```
int arr[] = {15, 11, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0}; // example array
int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
unordered_map<int, int> hash;
    for(i=n;i>=0;i--)
    {
        hash[i+1] = arr[i]; 
    }
    for(auto v : hash)
    {
        if(v.second==0) 
        {
            return v.second; 
        }
    }
```

```
int arr[] = {15, 11, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0};
int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==0) 
        {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that both functions as you've written them always return zero, which is not what you want.

---

Now, to answer the main question: No, this approach doesn't help.  In both cases you're just iterating over the values in the array until you hit on one that's a zero.  This is an O(n) operation in the worst case, and introducing an `unordered_map` here is just slowing things down.

The most similar thing you could do here that would actually *help* would be something like

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> lookup;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  lookup[arr[i]].push_back(i);
}
```

Now if you want to find a block with a zero in it you just an element from `lookup[0]`.

However, given that we only need to track the blocks with *zeroes* in them, and not immediately look up the blocks with, say, a 13 in them, we may as well just do:

```
std::vector<int> emptyBlocks;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  if(arr[i] == 0) { emptyBlocks.push_back(i); }
}
```

and then we can just grab empty blocks as we need them.

Note that you should take blocks from the *back* of `emptyBlocks` so that deleting them from the list doesn't require us to shift everything over.  If you need to take the smallest indices first for some reason, traverse `arr` backwards when building the list of empty blocks.

---

That said, when you're allocating blocks typically you're trying to find a range of *consecutive* empty blocks.  If *that's* the case, what you likely want is a way to look up the starting point of blocks of a given size.  And you probably want it to be ordered, too, so that you can ask for "the smallest block at least this large."

Comment: Will doing this `if(arr[i] == 0) { emptyBlocks.push_back(i); }` be faster than storing the `0`s in an array because I already have a function that stores the `0` in an array and counts the consecutive `0`s. Is there a faster way than arrays to iterate through elements in sequence to get the `0` values?

Comment: Will it be faster to put them in a vector than an array?  No.

Comment: If you are trying to allocate consecutive blocks, though, then it will likely be faster if you store the lengths of the blocks, like I described in the last paragraph.